# Implementing a variable shared between functions in Python 3.x

Tags: function, global-variables, python-3.3

Background information: 
I'm still learning python and one of the things I most enjoy is to work through my book and when I come to a new concept I find interesting I enjoy experimenting with the code to make different things. So now I have hit a snag and I can't seem to figure out how to get around it. I have tried searching and found some interesting solutions but I can't seem to implement them. 

Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from random import *

def window_size(wide,tall):
    tk = Tk()
    canvas = Canvas(tk, width=wide, height=tall)
    canvas.pack()

def random_rect(width, height):
    x1 = randrange(width)
    y1 = randrange(height)
    x2 = x1 + randrange(width)
    y2 = y1 + randrange(height)
    canvas.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2) # this is the trouble line

window_size(500,500)
random_rect(200, 200)
```

How I want it to work: 
So the idea is that I can call the function window_size and set the window to however large I want it to be. Then, if it worked, the random_rect function would draw a rectangle with random dimensions in my window.

What actually happens: 
The window_size function works fine. The random_rect function, on the other hand, has an issue with using "canvas.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2)" due to "global name canvas" being undefined.


I have tried returning different values in window_size but I haven't hit on the right one or can't figure out how to implement them. I tried creating classes and using self.canvas but couldn't get it to work right either.

Any help on this would be much appreciated. Its not so much about the implementation (no practical reason for this coding experiment) but I am eager to learn how to work around this problem as I can see how knowing the solution to this issue would be very useful in the future.

Thank you for the time and help!

**UPDATE:**
 So thanks to user Barmar below I was able to get my code working, but I also realized that what I wanted to achieve could be accomplished in another way as well and felt like sharing in case anyone comes across this someday:

```
from tkinter import *
from random import *

print("How many rectangles do you want?")
numrect = int(input())
print("How wide of a window do you want?")
winwide = int(input())
print("How tall of a window do you want?")
wintall = int(input())

tk = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(tk, width=winwide, height=wintall)
canvas.pack()

def random_rect(width, height):
    x1 = randrange(width)
    y1 = randrange(height)
    x2 = x1 + randrange(width)
    y2 = y1 + randrange(height)
    canvas.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2) # works good now!

for x in range(0, numrect):
    random_rect(winwide/2, wintall/2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return the canvas from `window_size`, and then pass it as an additional parameter to `random_rect`

```
def window_size(wide,tall):
    tk = Tk()
    canvas = Canvas(tk, width=wide, height=tall)
    canvas.pack()
    return canvas

def random_rect(canvas, width, height):
    x1 = randrange(width)
    y1 = randrange(height)
    x2 = x1 + randrange(width)
    y2 = y1 + randrange(height)
    canvas.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2) # this is the trouble line

c = window_size(500,500)
random_rect(c, 200, 200)
```

Comment: First off, thank you for taking the time to help me. I know its a simple question but it means alot coming from someone with your level of experience. As a follow up to this: Worked great! Is it bad practice to just call "random_rect(window_size(500,500),200,200)"?

Comment: No, that's perfectly fine, too.